# Egit: Meaning of branches in commit

Tags: git, egit

When I look in the history of my repository using Egit and clikc on a commit, I see in the panel on the left hand side:

> Branches: master, us1304, origin/HEAD, origin/master (and a lot more)

I assumed that this means that at the time of the commit, the commit belonged to these branches.

What I don't understand is that all commits in the history mention branch us1304, event commits from three years old. This branch was created only two weeks ago.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: I just restarted Eclipse and now it seems to be okay again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branches and tags that are shown left of the commit message in history view are not permanently there. They only show you that the specified branches and tags **currently** point at that commit (branches and tags are only pointers, remember)

Say your history looks like that:

```
o (master) Some commit
o Some older commit
```

Now you commit something into the branch master. As the pointer of the master branch now points to the new commit, your history will change like that:

```
o (master) new commit
o Some commit
o Some older commit
```

The `Some commit`-commit has lost its flag, as the pointer got moved away from it.

The same is valid for tags, even tough they normally dont move.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted Eclipse and now it seems to be okay again.

I have always been very pleased with Eclipse. However, since I updated to Eclipse Juno I experience lots of weird problems with short cuts not working anymore. And now I can add a malfunctioning Egit as well to this list. I sure hope in Eclipse Kepler these things work better.